# PayPal seller sandbox account - why can't I see any transactions?

Tags: java, paypal

I am writing my first PayPal app with the Classic API for Adaptive Payments. It's using Java Servlets with Tomcat.

The code seems to working correctly except I cannot see any transactions in the Seller sandbox account. The transactions are processed and do show up correctly in the Buyer's sandbox account.

I am using the sandbox credentials for both Buyer and Seller. I've tried credentials for the default "facilitator" account as well as creating a separate Business account as Seller. In either case, no transactions show in the Seller's history. I'm also using the testing AppID APP-80W284485P519543T.

I'd like to move on but without being able to see where the money goes, I'm not convinced this is working.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like maybe you've just got your accounts mixed up and the API credentials you're using in the app don't belong to the same sandbox account you're looking at when you check the history.

Or it could be a case where the API credentials do match the account you're logging into, but your app is actually sending the money to a 3rd party account..??

If the calls are working successfully then the money is going somewhere.  If it's not in the account you think it should be then it's gotta be something like what I mentioned.